# Для чего определяют двойные константы?

Tags: c

К примеру

```
#define _STRUCT_ struct
#define interface _STRUCT_
```

Comment: В этом примере нет констант, даже одинарных. Идентификатор `_STRUCT_` является зарезервированным и не должен задаваться в обычных программах.

Comment: @user7860670 задаваться да, но использоваться-то может.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В частности для обеспечения работоспособности старого кода. В данном случае со `_STRUCT_` я допускаю следующее предположение: имелся код, опирающийся на макро `_STRUCT_`, далее появилась идея использовать слово `interface`, как более говорящее в определённых контекстах, но для которого `struct` по-прежнему является целевым. Можно было бы сделать прямое макро определение типа `#define interface struct`, но в таком случае теряется возможность сквозного изменения `interface`, если вдруг `_STRUCT_` нужно будет превратить во что-то иное, например, сделать `#define _STRUCT_ class`. Поэтому и используется цепочное определение макросов, чтобы изменение в одном единственном месте прокидывалось в другие контексты.

Comment: Так один макрос можно в любой момент заменить на цепочку, не?

Comment: @Qwertiy не понял вопроса, если честно.

Comment: Ну если есть `#define interface struct`, то его можно так же в одном месте заменить на `#define interface _STRUCT_` - вроде не выглядит проблемой.

Comment: @Qwertiy Но если есть `#define _STRUCT_ struct` и `#define interface struct`, то для того, чтобы и то и другое изменить на `class`, нужно менять в двух местах, а в варианте, приведенном в вопросе - в одном

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов, я по вопросу подумал, что `_STRUCT_` больше нигде не используется...

Comment: @Qwertiy, тогда действительно непонятно было бы - зачем их два

Comment: @Qwertiy вопрос себя исчерпал, если я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, ну если ответ сводится к тому, что `_STRUCT_` используется многократно, то да. Если можешь придумать, зачем он нужен при однократном использовании, то с удовольствием прочитаю.

Comment: @Qwertiy если нигде, кроме приведённых двух строк `_STRUCT_` не фигурирует, то, конечно, необходимости в нём нет. Препроцессор заменяет макро до финального значения, какой бы длины цепочка дефайнов ни была.

Comment: Ну так зачем создавать две константы(макроса)? Если хочешь поменять его потом на класс создай ты один макрос и дело с концом.

Comment: @RundogieRundogie, ну иногда может быть ради разворачивания имён, но в твоём примере этим и не пахнет.

Comment: @RundogieRundogie какой один? Вот ситуация: есть уже миллионы строк кода с использованием `_STRUCT_ `, и он должен работать, не смотря на появление `interface` и т.п.

Comment: а что за идентификатор _STRUCT_? Нигде не могу найти про него.

Comment: @RundogieRundogie а откуда вы его исходно взяли? Вопрос-то ваш.